# Where clause using Expression tree builder

Tags: linq, expression-trees

I have to fetch data from database and filter data using the linq where clause.
My filter is an integer column and it contains value more than 1000.
What i am doing in the code is, breaking this huge array into chunk of 1000's of each and putting it in the where clause of a base query

```
int j = 0;
int batchsize = 1000;
while ((j * batchsize) < items.Count())
{
List<long> batch = items.Skip(j * batchsize)
.Take(batchsize).ToList();
prequery = prequery.Where(x => batch.Contains(x.Id));
j++;
}
```

the query which is getting generated in sql is below,

```
SELECT 
    x.name,
    x.email
FROM
    table x
WHERE
    x.Id IN (1,2,3,...,1000) AND
    x.Id IN (1001,1002,1003....,2000)
```

i want the query to be generated as below,

```
SELECT 
    x.name,
    x.email
FROM
    table x
WHERE
    x.Id IN (1,2,3,...,1000) OR
    x.Id IN (1001,1002,1003....,2000)
```

can i achieve this using expression tree builder and generate the query dynamically, if so please help in doing

Comment: sql in operator can be used in linq using extension method Contains.. more on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could use the "Concat" API:

```
int j = 0;
int batchsize = 1000;


IQueryable<YourType> finalQuery = null;

while ((j * batchsize) < items.Count())
{
   List<long> batch = items.Skip(j * batchsize)
   .Take(batchsize).ToList();

   if (finalQuery == null) {
       finalQuery = prequery.Where(x => batch.Contains(x.Id));
   }
   else
       finalQuery = finalQuery.Concat (prequery.Where(x => batch.Contains(x.Id)));

   j++;
}
```

This will logically get you what you want: basically you want an "OR" operation between batches. Concat is translated into an "UNION ALL" database call.

BUT ... I don't understand why are you doing this, after all you are grabbing all your data, chunks are not helping you because in the end there will be only one statement executed.